# Skill leveling system with different skill level titles

Tags: javascript, game

I'm making a text-based RPG in JavaScript. I made a skill leveling system that works, but I feel like the function arguments get passed around a lot and, the code is not very scalable. Do you have any suggestions on how I can improve this code? Ideally, I want to call only one function like:
`addExperience(25, charisma);`

**What my code does:**
The `properties` object gives each skill level a title. Currently, all skills have the same title. In the future, these will have different titles and number of titles.

The `player` object has a skill `level` and `experience` key for each skill, so the skills can level independently.

*I've also posted the HTML and CSS code for completion. However, this is not important because I only wrote it to test the JavaScript code, and it is not part of the game.*

```js
// Skill variable
const properties = {
  strength: [
    "Dabbler",
    "Skilled",
    "Untrained",
    "Proficient",
    "Amateur",
    "Superb",
    "Master",
  ],
  endurance: [
    "Dabbler",
    "Skilled",
    "Untrained",
    "Proficient",
    "Amateur",
    "Superb",
    "Master",
  ],
  charisma: [
    "Dabbler",
    "Skilled",
    "Untrained",
    "Proficient",
    "Amateur",
    "Superb",
    "Master",
  ],
};

// Player variables
const player = {
  stats: {
    strength: {
      level: 0,
      experience: 0,
    },
    endurance: {
      level: 0,
      experience: 0,
    },
    charisma: {
      level: 0,
      experience: 0,
    },
  },
};

function getExperienceToNextLevel(level, skill) {
  if (level < skill.length) {
    return ((level * (level + 1)) / 2) * 1000;
  }
}

function addExperience(amount, stat, skill) {
  if (stat.level !== skill.length - 1) {
    stat.experience += amount;
    while (stat.experience >= getExperienceToNextLevel(stat.level, skill)) {
      stat.experience -= getExperienceToNextLevel(stat.level, skill);
      ++stat.level;
    }
  }
  display(stat, skill);
}

function display(stat, skill) {
  document.getElementById("level-display").innerHTML = `${stat.level} ${
    skill[stat.level]
  }`;

  document.getElementById("xp-display").innerHTML = `${stat.experience}`;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #ff930f;
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(255, 147, 15, 1) 0%,
    rgba(255, 249, 91, 1) 100%
  );
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.title {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: #fff;
  margin: 5% auto;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.display {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: #fff;
  margin: 5%;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.xp-buttons {
  text-align: center;
}

.xp-buttons button {
  background-color: #333;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 999rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 2.5rem;
  max-width: auto;
  min-width: 5rem;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.xp-buttons button:hover {
  background-color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="description" content="JavaScript - Debugger" />
    <title>JavaScript - Debugger</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <h1 class="title">JavaScript - Debugger</h1>
      <div class="display">
        <h2>Level: <span id="level-display"></span></h2>
        <h2>XP: <span id="xp-display"></span></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="xp-buttons">
        <button
          onclick="addExperience(50, player.stats.charisma, properties.charisma)"
        >
          50 XP
        </button>
        <button
          onclick="addExperience(1000, player.stats.charisma,properties.charisma)"
        >
          1000 XP
        </button>
        <button
          onclick="addExperience(0, player.stats.charisma,properties.charisma)"
        >
          Update
        </button>
      </div>
    </main>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Test code is perfectly fine, and it does provide context on the use of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A short review;

- I don't like the signature of the function

  ```
  addExperience(50, player.stats.charisma, properties.charisma)
  ```

  could be

  ```
  addExperience(50, player, "charisma");
  ```

  or even

  ```
  player.addExperience(50, "charisma");
  ```

  and if it was me, I would make it more Yoda like

  or even

  ```
  player.addExperience("charisma", 50);
  ```
- I would keep track of total experience, and not reset it every time you reach a new level. In case you ever want to rebalance the levels of existing characters.
- I would recommend reading up on the [MVC model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/MVC). If you follow it, then `addExperience` does not call `display`
- Its stub code, but `display` is too generic a name
- You seem to treat stats and skills as the same, to me they are not?
- `properties` should probably be `statTitles`?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! The objects indeed need some reorganizing. I will try to implement the Yoda-like signature. Although a `player` like object still needs to be passed into the function. Because in the future, I want to add skills to NPC's.

Comment: `addExperience(50, player, "charisma");` is not very friendly to some js code minifier.

Comment: @tsh Do you have a link or logic to back that up? Super interested.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31361878

Comment: Maybe I am having a brain fart, but that link says that prototype design is not friendly for minifiers? The code you quote does not use that?